# Make redirect from www to non-www and allow futher processing

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect site from www to non-www.

The main issue is that .htaccess file of CMS is very complicated.

Otherwise this instruction in the start of the .htaccess should have worked

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ecotrans-spb.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ecotrans-spb.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What flags should I set here instead of these to allow .htaccess process the URL further?

Generic CMS .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 401 /password.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ecotrans-spb.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ecotrans-spb.ru/$1 [R=301]


# Админка теперь по адресу /simpla
RewriteRule ^admin/?$  simpla [L]


# Каталог товаров
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=ProductsView&category=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=ProductsView&category=$1&brand=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$    index.php?module=ProductView&product_url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/?$    index.php?module=ProductsView [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^brands/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?module=ProductsView&brand=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/]+)/page_([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=ProductsView&brand=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

# Поиск товаров
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?module=ProductsView&keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/?$  index.php?module=ProductsView [L,QSA]

# Блог
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$    index.php?module=BlogView&url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$    index.php?module=BlogView [L,QSA]

# Корзина и заказы
RewriteRule ^cart/?$    index.php?module=CartView   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cart/([^/]+)/?$    index.php?module=CartView&add_variant=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cart/remove/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=CartView&delete_variant=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^order/([^/]+)/?$   index.php?module=OrderView&url=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^order/?$   index.php?module=OrderView  [L,QSA]

# Для пользователей
RewriteRule ^user/login/?$  index.php?module=LoginView  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/register/?$   index.php?module=RegisterView  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/logout/?$ index.php?module=LoginView&action=logout  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/password_remind/?$    index.php?module=LoginView&action=password_remind  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/password_remind/([0-9a-z]+)/?$    index.php?module=LoginView&action=password_remind&code=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/?$    index.php?module=UserView  [L,QSA]

# Google sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml?$  sitemap.php  [L,QSA]

# XML
RewriteRule ^yandex.xml?$   yandex.php  [L,QSA]

# feedback
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?module=FeedbackView  [L,QSA]

#downloads
RewriteRule ^order/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$   index.php?module=OrderView&url=$1&file=$2  [L,QSA]


# Статические страницы
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?module=PageView&page_url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?$    index.php?module=MainView&page_url= [L,QSA]

# Ресайз картинок на лету
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^files/products/(.+) resize/resize.php?file=$1&token=%{QUERY_STRING}
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)files/products/(.*)\?([A-z0-9]*) 
#RewriteRule ^files/products/(.+) resize/resize.php?file=%2&token=%3 [L,NE]
```

Comment: Any reason for processing the rules further instead of redirecting to "correct" host name?

Comment: This ain't gonna work, unless of course you do a lot of repetitions, long story short: **it's not worth it**

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `L` from the last line will allow it to continue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ecotrans-spb.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ecotrans-spb.ru/$1 [R=301]
```

`[L]` is a flag that, if this rule matches, then no other rule matching will be performed.

Comment: Nope...I believe the [R=301] will take effect...Am I wrong?

Comment: `[R=301]` will tell the browser (and search engines) that the page has  been permanently moved to the new address

Comment: If I just remove L I get 500 Internal Server Error, and if I remove these RewriteCond and RewriteRule, all works ok (of course without www redirect)

Comment: Try remove all but the first three lines to see if it still causes the 500 internal error. If it doesn't can you edit your first post and copy in the full contents of your htaccess file

Comment: I've added generic CMS .htaccess

Comment: @Howlin,  @Lambrusco.Newbie;  You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings. -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r